# How can I format string type of time/date in React.js

Tags: javascript

Time format i have is `2022-02-16T12:33:44Z`

How can is make this

```
2022-02-16

12:33
```

including br tag.

what i tried was `date.split("T")` but don't know what to do next

Comment: You can try [DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat)

Comment: You can easily achieve the desired behavior through simple [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) methods. Also, React has nothing to do with this, it's just plain old JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

```
const str = "2022-02-16T12:33:44Z"
str.split("T")[0]
str.split("T")[1].slice(0,-4)
```

Output

`2022-02-16`

`12:33`